# Sort Core data entity by String (Swift3)

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, swift4

This is my code:

```
let fetche:NSFetchRequest<Location> Location.fetchRequest()
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key:#keyPath(Location.locationName), ascending:  true)
fetche.sortDescriptors = [sort]

let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "countryId CONTAINS %@ ",results.countryId!)
fetche.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1])
```

I need to sort data by the string "Cho" in the location name.

Comment: It's not clear what that means. You want strings that contain "Cho" to go ahead of those that don't contain "Cho", maybe?

Comment: I have core data entity , I need sort this data in entity by string ("cho")

Comment: Yes, that's what you said in your question. It's not any clearer from your comment. Can you give an example of what the strings contain and what result you want?

Comment: I have many countries such as 

USA , KSA , Palestine .... 

I'm used picker view to view data and I want to make first row "Choose country " , I'm add "choose country" in countries entity , now I want to sort this data to view choose country in first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your comments correctly, you have location names that contain strings naming countries ("USA", "KSA", "Palestine", etc) and also one that says "Choose country...", and you want to know how to sort "Choose country..." to the top of the list.

Ideally your data model would only include, well, data. Since "Choose country" is not a location name, it shouldn't be included in the list of countries. If you want to show this text above a list of countries, two better options are:

1. Don't include that text in the picker. Instead, put it above or next to the picker in a `UILabel`.
2. If you want to include that text in the picker, write the picker delegate so that it returns "Choose country" for the first entry, and then uses your country list for all other rows.

There are ways to sort the list as you suggest, but there are no **good** ways.

Comment: If you want to include that text in the picker, write the picker delegate so that it returns "Choose country" for the first entry, and then uses your country list for all other rows. 

can you write example about it ?

Comment: No. It's not hard. When asked for row 0, the delegate always returns "Choose country". When asked for any other row, the delegate returns data from your list of countries.